# How to get a name from Tempfriend object (1) in django?

Tags: django

my **tempfriends/models.py**

```
class Tempfriend(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(
        user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="belongs_to")
```

as you see, tempfriends have a relation with usermodels.

so when user make a moneybook, user can choose there companion(tempfriends), but there is a problem.

form.companion print out :

Tempfriend object (1)

these are the code.

**moneybook_form.html**

```
<div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.companion.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 flex inline border-b my-2 py-3">
                    <div class="w-3/4">
                        {{form.companion}}
                    </div>
                    <div class= "w-1/4 flex justify-center ">
                        <a href="{% url 'tempfriends:create' %}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.companion.errors %}
                {% for error in form.companion.errors %}
                    ><span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

how can I print **object name** instead of **Tempfriend object (1)**?

Comment: You need to define a `__str__` method for your model to return what you want instead of "%model_name% object"